# Create a unique postal system for an unrecognised nation

Tags: government, united-nations

I am building a nation in a world similar to ours which is unrecognised by other nations.

The government is not a member of the universal postal union, and wants to create a postal system for its citizens.

I need ideas that think outside of the box. Should the nation still use a system of roads with property addresses? How should subdivided properties have addresses allocated when they are split?

Share ideas of locating premises and creating a postal system unlike other nations

**Bonus** Figure out a way for the nation to integrate with other postal systems and ecommerce without being recognised by them

Comment: Welcome to worlbuilding, as you might notice visiting the [help] and taking the [tour], we solve world building problems, we don't generate ideas without a specific scope. Moreover, sending internal mail has nothing to do with the recognition from other nations.

Comment: What's their tech level, ie do they use personal teleportation or all get around on foot, or where in-between? How do they live, cottage farms all bartering in local communities with little money, and the central government paying for access to e-commerce through tax? Are they an industrialized civilised with nodal distribution between farming and cities all connected by roads, or do they all live in a system of sand caves in the desert, making money through banditry and trade of gems? We need a well-defined question. Please [edit] to give us a bit more detail.

Comment: Are you laboring under the mistaken impression that all the countries in the world use postal addresses of the form Country, Province, City, Street Name, Number, Apartment? As any aspiring computer programmer should know, this is **not** the case. For example, in Japan [they don't use street names](http://www.upu.int/fileadmin/documentsFiles/activities/addressingUnit/jpnEn.pdf) in postal addresses, postal numbers may refer to more than one building and are counted inside a "block". [UPU guide here](http://www.upu.int/en/activities/addressing/postal-addressing-systems-in-member-countries.html).

Comment: @AlexP, a fair number of countries don't have any sort of sensible address system, especially when you get into Africa. Solving this is actually a serious issue for the likes of Amazon.

Comment: If the addressee lives on the farm on the range or in a hut in the woods, the map of the location drawn on the envelope will do. Read [this great article](https://bigthink.com/strange-maps/the-map-as-address-cryptic-letter-reaches-icelandic-destination) on the weirdest addresses and bizarre mail situations, it has lots of links to other articles like that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to start my answer with a couple of assumptions;

1) Given your mention of ecommerce, I'm assuming this is an industrialised and technically proficient nation

2) Given your use of the word 'unrecognised' instead of 'undiscovered' I also assume that your nation is aware of the existing conventions of addressing for postal services that are in use around the world and want something different that meets their specific needs.

Now to the matter at hand; the existing postal system was designed for a different time and the use of the postal service for parcels as opposed to letters has increased due to online shopping increasing parcels and email and the like decreasing letters. There's no point sending someone a bill when you an email them in today's world, and while that means they can read that bill at work, on their phone, pretty much wherever they are makes is far more convenient to send letter sized information packets over email rather than by post.

Parcels just haven't caught up with that fact, so in the modern world people get their parcels sent to their work (because in economies with equitable gender participation no-one's at home to receive them) or they get a secure delivery drawer or deposit box at their nearest post office from which to retrieve it.

Bottom line is that one's home address is no longer a reliable indicator of where a person spends their time and therefore isn't a good system to copy, especially when you consider how in some nations (like many African ones) a robust system of street addressing doesn't exist, either because it's too hard or no-one has thought to bother with it.

In this environment, the obvious solution is a set of latitude and longitude coordinates based on where a mobile phone is expected to be at a given delivery time.

If your nation has smart phones, most of these will have location tracking on. You can start building a map of where people are at a given time during a workday, and plan your delivery routes via that. In theory, this is a better solution to the physical delivery problem than addresses because addresses assume that the person knows in advance where they are going to be on a given day. But, if you deliver to where they actually ARE (or where you think they're going to be based on previous history) then you are going to get more parcels to the person in the first pass.

Sure there are problems with this;

Some people work in secure environments, and can't receive parcels or can't put on location tracking.

Some people won't be predictable, like trades or salespeople and the like who travel around a lot with their jobs.

Some people don't want their deliveries taken to a work site for various reasons, including a boss who sees it as a sign of a distractable worker.

So, those people can still provide a valid postal address if they can, or get a temporary delivery drop box that they can go check.

Now for the bonus question; Most databases of valid addresses in developed countries are already mapped to geo-coordinates. The GNAP database of Australian addresses is an example of this. To map this to other postal services, you literally just have to reverse engineer a similar system to the anticipated lat/long pair of a person's whereabouts. You could even do it via the phone number. If your computer is capable of inputting the recipient's mobile phone number directly, and possibly an anticipated delivery time, it can convert that information to a lat/long, and possibly therefore a geo-anchored address that makes sense to your postman.

Ironically enough, this would also be Amazon's wet dream; imagine if their future delivery drones could be keyed with a mobile phone number and just go to it and drop their package. No addresses at all, just a physical location of a device that is always on the recipient's person, more or less.

Comment: "_imagine if their future delivery drones could be keyed with a mobile phone number and just go to it and drop their package_" I believe a number of late members of the taliban and al qaeda have exactly this customer experience, though the transaction they were involved in wasn't strictly commercial.